# Linux or BSD "smart" watch?

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, bluetooth, bsd

Many many years ago (2001) IBM were working on a Linux watch with Bluetooth (if memory serves). I wonder if anything like it is available now?

Specifically, I'd want a watch that tells time and runs Linux (or BSD or some such system) with some sort of wireless connectivity (WLAN or Bluetooth) which I can SSH into to set alarms and such.

Not useful, perhaps, but very geeky!

Anyone heard of such a product?

(It could also double as an SD card equivalent.)

Comment: Link to the IBM project: http://www.research.ibm.com/WearableComputing/linuxwatch/linuxwatch.html. Can't say I've heard of any such device, or think that it would sell in this age.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [MetaWatch.com](http://www.MetaWatch.com), [GetInPulse.com](http://www.GetInPulse.com), [imWatch.com](http://www.imWatch.com) and 
[WIMM.com](http://www.wimm.com/).  They all do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you were looking for, but there are a few watches here which can double up as memory sticks: http://www.thinkgeek.com/brain/whereisit.cgi?t=watch&x=0&y=0

Comment: It's not what I wanted, but the things are funny.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like IBM ever had any competition for that market.

http://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Alinuxdevices.com+wrist+watch